# imacros extraction using two loops

Tags: vbscript, imacros

Hi  My requirement is I have to read one csv file which contains 100 urls and for each url I have to scrape the data. Each url webpage contains 100 lines of data suppose which I am extracting on changing the POS value .So my question is how do I maintain two loops using VB script and macro.
Please help...
If I am witing two loops the inner loop should break if no data i.e if #EANF# is found

Comment: Sure we´ll help you. But specify exactly what your problem is, please, and show what you´ve tried, no matter how bad it might look.

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding...

Comment: Don´t thank. Modify and extend your question!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what data you're trying to extract, but this script will get your foot in the door..

```
1 VERSION BUILD 7020226 RECORDER=CR
2 SET !DATASOURCE inputURLs.csv
3 SET !DATASOURCE COLUMNS 1
4 SET !LOOP 2
5 SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
6 SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

7 URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
8 TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:EXAMPLE EXTRACT=TXT
9 SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER:C:\Output FILE=output.csv
```

This script uses a filename called "inputURLs.csv" located in your default Datasources folder, begins looping on row 2 (assuming you have a header row), extracts the text a certain  tag contains for each URL that's inputted and extracts the results to a file called "output.csv" located a folder called "Output" on your C: Drive. You'll need to replace line 8 with the page elements that you want to extract.
This can be built right into the IDE, no VB scripting required.